# Idris FFI "symbol not found"

Tags: ffi, idris

I've been messing around with Idris lately and decided to try playing around with its `Network.Socket` library. I fired up the REPL, imported the module, and created a socket using the `socket` command. Upon attempting to execute the `IO` operation, I was met with the following error:

```
failed to construct ffun from (Builtins.MkPair (FFI_C.C_Types (Int)) (Int) (FFI_C.C_IntT (Int) (FFI_C.C_IntNative)) (2),Builtins.MkPair (FFI_C.C_Types (Int)) (Int) (FFI_C.C_IntT (Int) (FFI_C.C_IntNative)) (1),[])
Symbol "socket" not found
user error (Could not call foreign function "socket" with args [2,1,0])
```

To see whether the issue was `Network.Socket` specific, or just FFI in general, I made a dummy function.

```
printf : String -> IO ()
printf = foreign FFI_C "printf" (String -> IO ())
```

Executed `:x printf "Hello World"` yields a similar error:

```
Symbol "printf" not found
user error (Could not call foreign function "printf" with args ["hello world"])
```

Despite all this, `putStr` works fine.

I am running Idris 9.20, installed through cabal with `-f FFI` set at compile. I am using libffi version 3.4 installed through MacPorts.

Comment: I get the same error with idris 0.9.20.1 installed via brew, however putting printf into main and calling :exec works with a warning.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this has to do with the fact that the Idris FFI operates differently depending on whether code is being compiled or interpreted.  When code is being compiled, the FFI requires that at the stage of C codegen, the named C function be in scope, and that when linking the C executable, the correct name is linked in.  Since Idris's RTS links against libc, this makes a lot of names from libc work without any extra effort (certain names might require a `%include` to make sure that the correct C header file is included to put them in scope).  When code is being interpreted, the interpreter looks up FFI calls in a list of libraries that have been loaded dynamically, which requires a different directive: `%dynamic` in the file, or `:dynamic` in the interpreter.  By default, no dynamic libraries are loaded, so even standard names in libc are not in scope.  This can be remedied by including `%dynamic "libc"` in the file, or using the `:dynamic "libc"` at the REPL commandline for one session.